# How do I update SQL string dynamically?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb, database-trigger

I have to store the substrings of a string by using concat.
Example:

```
SET X VARCHAR(10);
LOOP:
SET X = CONCAT(X,'new_value');
END LOOP
```

What set does is it stores a new value in X and not all the concatened value.

How do I achieve this?

`+=` does not work

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you mean? I'm not clear from what you've mentioned in the question

Comment: This is not viable mysql code - are you sure the question is tagged correctly - if it is can you include all of the stored program this code is on.

Comment: Also if you concat includes a  null value then the result is null so use coalesce to cope with that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

`SET X VARCHAR(10);`  That does not work.  Perhaps you meant `DECLARE x VARCHAR(10);`

But probably better is to skip the declaration and simply do

```
SET @x := CONCAT(@x, 'appended string');
```

or

```
SELECT @x := CONCAT(@x, 'appended string');
```